# Phonegap Android Cordova buid Failed

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying build a Android project in Phonegap.

```
On "cordova build" command i am getting the below error

  My project folder Path: Audio\platforms\android\...

CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\ExposedJsApi.java:43: error: cannot find symbol
CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\ExposedJsApi.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\ExposedJsApi.java:43: error: cannot find symbol
CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\IceCreamCordovaWebViewClient.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
CordovaLib\src\com\squareup\okhttp\internal\http\HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:347: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
```

[javac]     @JavascriptInterface
...

Basically they are pointing to my "CordovaLib\src" @JavascriptInterface. Why is this, Where do i am missing

Please Help ..

Answer (score -1):

```
CordovaLib\src\com\squareup\okhttp\internal\http\HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:347: method does not override or implement a method from a supertyp **this error showing**
```

Some out of date packages on you machine were creating this. please  upgrade  everything it will works fine.

Comment: Do i have to update my Android SDK manager, i have installed  API10,11,17,19,20,21 One month back.

Comment: I have created the project -> added android platform -> added plugins -> and trying to build it

Comment: After update also it din't make any difference Sport.                just I have created the project -> added android platform -> added plugins -> and trying to build it. I am not changing any thing.

Comment: No Sport, Not working. After update also Not even single build error resolved.